# Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type

Tags: java, android-studio, spring-boot, rest, retrofit

me encuentro con un error que no sé por donde cogerlo. Estoy realizando un api/rest de android studio (RetroFit) con SpringBoot (como servidor).
Resulta que me encuentro con este error:

```
 Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
```

Expongo retrofit interface:

```
 @PUT("editPlayer{id}")
    Call<PlayerDto> editPlayer(@Body PlayerDto player, @Path("id") int id);
```

Expongo llamada al servidor:

```
Settings.RESPONSE_CLIENT.getService()
.editPlayer(editedPlayer, 53)
.enqueue(new Callback<PlayerDto>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<PlayerDto> call, Response<PlayerDto> response) {
      editedPlayer = response.body();
      typeError = 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<PlayerDto> call, Throwable t) {
      Log.e("Error: ", t.getMessage());
      typeError = 2;
   }
});
```

Expongo servidor Controller:

```
@PutMapping("/editPlayer{id}")
    public Player editPlayer(@RequestBody Player player, @Param("id") int id) {
        return service.editPlayer(player.getUsername(), id);
    }
```

Expongo servidor PlayerService:

```
public Player editPlayer(String username, int id) {

        repoPlayer.editUserNamePlayer(username, id);
        Optional<Player> player = repoPlayer.findById(id);

        return player.get();
    }
```

Expongo IPlayerRepository, aunque solo es la "Query" :

```
@Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Player p SET p.username= :username WHERE p.id= :id")
    public void editUserNamePlayer(@Param("username")String username, @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Realizo pruebas con Insomnia y no tengo ningún problema adjunto imagen:
[image: imagen de captura test insomnia put api/rest]

Pero no tengo manera de enviar la id desde android studio, parece que se le envia "null".
Ni ingresandolo a mano ni recogiendolo por parámetro.

Necesito ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje indica el problema:

> Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into
> a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider
> declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

tu parametro `id` esta siendo definido con un valor `null`, **una variable primitiva no puede ser declarada con valor `null`**.

en el ejemplo que expones no creo que se presente el problema ya que id es diferente a null:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero debes asegurar que el valor que envìas como id en este mètodo `public Player editPlayer(String username, int id) {`

Comment: En el ejemplo que expone no se le presenta el problema ya que el **id** se lo esta pasando como *query param* (**?id=53**) `http://localhost:8080/game/editPlayer?id=53`. El problema de él es que está armando mal el request en su aplicación android

Comment: Estoy comentando "el ejemplo que expones no creo que se presente el problema"

Comment: Aclaré el porqué no se le va a presentar el problema ya que dijiste que "no creo que se te presente el problema"

Comment: A su vez, en lugar de tratar de explicar lo que significa la excepción que recibe, trato de generarle una ayuda aclarando que su dificultad radica en armar el request

Comment: Además ahora que releo tu edición noto que la captura que subiste es de la respuesta y no de la petición que hace por Insomia. Con lo que tu explicación de que el **id** es distinto de `null`, si bien es acertado, es incorrecto porque ahí no es donde está especificado el id

Comment: Si puedes responder a la pregunta, mejor agrega una respuesta... jajaja